# How to stop all running timer

Tags: c#

How to stop all timer in c# ?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.stop();
```

this code didn't work , I have 5 timer and i'm lazy to write timer1.stop timer2.stop and more ...

How can i stop all timer ?

Comment: Put them is a `List<Timer>` and write a loop? Also, "didn't work" isn't very specific. What didn't exactly work? any error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the creation of your timers, do something like this

```
var Timerlist = new List<Timer>();


Timer timer1 = new Timer();
Timerlist.Add(timer1);
```

....

```
foreach(var timer in Timerlist)
{
  timer.Start();
}
```

....

```
foreach(var timer in Timerlist)
{
  timer.Stop();
}
```